# Confusion about spark streaming's transform function

Tags: scala, apache-spark, streaming, bigdata

I am a bit confused about the transform function of a DStream. For example, if I have the following.

```
val statusesSorted = statuses.transform(rdd => rdd.sortByKey())
```

Would the whole DStream be sorted by key or the individual RDDs inside the DStream would be sorted separately. If that is indeed the case, how can I sort keys of the whole DStream.

Comment: how should  sorting the entire Stream work? You can't know what elements will come next...

Comment: I mean for example when you use reduceByKeyAndWindow, you also specify the windows size. Is it possible to sort the whole window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `transform` function in Spark allows you to perform any Spark transformation on the `RDDs` within your DStream.

The `map` transform does a similar operation but on an element to element basis, whereas the `transform` operation on dstream allows you do the transformation on a complete RDD.

To answer your questions,

> Would the whole DStream be sorted by key or the individual RDDs inside
>   the DStream would be sorted separately.

It will sort the individual RDDs in your dstream.

> If that is indeed the case, how can I sort keys of the whole DStream.

To answer this, understand that Spark processes one batch at a time and the records in a batch correspond to the RDDs. So sorting the records in a batch(i.e. an RDD) will make sense because they form the data for computation. Sorting a dstream is not logical.

Comment: OK, but when you use reduceByKeyAndWindow, you also specify the window size. For example you could be streaming at 1 second, but window is 60 seconds. Is it possible to sort data in that 60 seconds window. I would like to use such functionality because, for example, I want to list the top counts for a window.

Comment: OK, got it, In the reduceByKeyAndWindow's case, an RDD just become the one with 60 seconds interval of data.

Comment: Yes, that will be the output of your window operation.